# Security for secret key of server in Identity-based Encryption

Tags: pairings

In the key set up phase, server generates Pub=s.P, where s is the secret key.Then , it gives clients Pub,P as public parameters and pairing descriptions. Is it possible for clients to pre-compute  r.P repeatedly  until r.P=Pub so that r=s?

Comment: What you are asking is whether it is possible for clients to solve the elliptic-curve discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: fkraiem.I have read some papers. In those papers, they give like that.  Is it possible or difficult?

Comment: Have you tried to find some information about this problem, for examples in your textbook, lecture notes, or on the Internet?

Comment: Now, I am trying elliptic-curve discrete logarithm.thz for guide.

Answer (score 1):

You ask if it's possible: yes it is. But you have to ask yourself if it's **feasible in practice**.

This introduces the notion of **complexity**.

The method you mention is the naive brute force calculation for the discrete logarithm problem and its complexity is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the order of the elliptic curve.

Several algorithms are more efficients like [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) and [baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) for example (complexity in $0(\sqrt{n})$).

There exist other methods but first, try to understand the two mentioned above. This will familiarize you with the discrete logarithm problem.